# Remove Unused Declaration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ide

[image]

I'm trying to build a script to retrieve data from an API, and fill an array that i'm trying to create automatically in Google Apps Script.

When I try to construct the columns and fill each column with the value that it should get, the variable column (`colonnes`) in the script turn gray ( For Information this method works when I tried it before with other APIS), so i can't modify columns of my array.

```
function GetAllProduct() {

    var token=ConnectAlkemics();

    var headers = {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "fr",
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'expires': '-1',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'x-alk-priority': '9'
    };

    var options = {
        'method' : "GET",
        "headers" : headers
    };

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("GTIN");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RESULTATS");
    ss.clear();

    var total = 0;
    var debut = 2;
    var moregtin = true
    var lignegtin = 1;

    var colonnes = [
        "GTIN", 
        "Libelle long", 
        "Libelle Court", 
        "Fournisseur", 
        "Code Tiers",
        "Marque",     
     ];
 }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `colonnes`? There is nothing happening with it...

Comment: `so i can't modify columns of my array.` No, it's opposite. Because you're not  modifying the `columns of my array`, that variable is gray.

Comment: Your variable turns grey if you haven't used it anywhere.  It's the editors way of identifying variables that you are not using.   Just use it somewhere else and it will get darker or discard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function GetAllProduct() {
    var token=ConnectAlkemics();
    var headers = {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "fr",
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'expires': '-1',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'x-alk-priority': '9'
    };

    var options = {
        'method' : "GET",
        "headers" : headers
    };
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    var source = ss.getSheetByName("GTIN");
    var sh = ss.getActive().getSheetByName("RESULTATS");
    sh.clear();

    var total = 0;
    var debut = 2;
    var moregtin = true
    var lignegtin = 1;

    var colonnes = [
        "GTIN", 
        "Libelle long", 
        "Libelle Court", 
        "Fournisseur", 
        "Code Tiers",
        "Marque",     
     ];
     sh.getRange(1,1,[colonnes].length,colonnes.length).setValues([colonnes]);
 }
```